# Повторить запрос в websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

Мне нужно перенести функционал торговой площадки в телеграмм. А именно чат покупателя с клиентом. Уточню что нужно его повторить, используя все апи и ссылки которые использует сам сайт. Так в чем моя проблема.

Чат площадки базируется на вебсокетах. У меня есть и ссылка на вебсокет и какие данные нужно туда передавать - это я получил анализируя трафик через Charles (популярный аналог: Fiddler, Wireshark). Повторяю все те же данные которые там есть, но ответа от сервера не получаю, и хочу отметить что если отправить серверу что-то не правильное то он ответит ошибкой, что доказывает акивное соединение.

Код котрый я использовал:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def main():
    url = "wss://chat.api?access_token=123bdc-456as-789ac-35fd87"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as client: 
        await client.send("CONNECT accept-version:1.1,1.2 heart-beat:0,2000 deviceType:MOBILE")
        response = await client.recv()
        print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Заранее всех благодарю за помощь. Если нужны правки пишите все отредактирую.

Comment: Приложи пример к api из документации.

Comment: Документации нет, я все делаю путем анализа трафика